# Ssh with intellij only works with password

Tags: ssh, intellij-idea

Whenever I ssh via intellij, with a password it works fine. But whenever I start using my key, it just fails.

Here is a video detailing the exact situation: http://youtu.be/gSycl4Jc-Ys

Whenever I use my password its cool, when i use my key, it just fails on me and says auth cancel or as above since I tried so many times that its failed too many times even though my terminal ssh works...?

It also fails if I go into tools and select start ssh session...

Very confused and would appreciate any help! Same happens if I go into tools and select start ssh session...

just tried to do sftp with macs built in sftp and it worked.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/im2i3zwy3op1ezp/Screenshot%202015-02-02%2001.26.56.png?dl=0

i dont understand life anymore

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I figured it out, seems like intellij requires there be a passphrase on the ssh key file. It works now. I just generated a new key with a passphrase and everything worked. Just incase anyone else has the same problem as me I figured id answer as a Q&A.

Comment: Also note that you have to specify the passphrase, it doesn't pickup on ssh-agent or prompt per connection.